# Refresh windows 8 drive is locked

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-refresh, refresh

I gave up when trying to restore my windows 8.1 pro. I used recover -> refresh feature in windows 8.1 FYI, my laptop use OEM license, but unfortunately, my OEM partition's gone. But I've created my custom image using `recimg -CreateImg`. Here's my `reagentc /info` output result:

```
Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration
Information:

    Windows RE status:         Enabled
    Windows RE location:       \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE
    Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 13c7df11-e1a7-11e4-b7e9-a1b143249d28
    Recovery image location:
    Recovery image index:      0
    Custom image location:     \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition4\Image
    Custom image index:        1

REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.
```

When I went to recovery boot and trying to refresh the windows installation, it showed error message that "The drive where the windows installed is locked". After googling and found solution by [checking disk](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-1852187/drive-windows-installed-locked.html) for corrupt partition and whether is it read only or not, but got no luck because my disk/partition wasn't in read-only state from the first at all. Another solution is [rebuilding bootloader](https://neosmart.net/wiki/the-drive-where-windows-is-installed-is-locked/) but still got no luck at all.

FYI, I used GPT instead of MBR for my disk partition. And I forced to use secure boot (UEFI only). I placed my custom image in different partition (it's only basic partition data just like windows partition, it's not special partition like OEM partition) with my windows partition. I tried to copy my custom image to my windows partition using `recimg /setcurrent` to update the latest custom image location but still got no luck.

I know it's duplicate with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/642276/how-to-unlock-a-hard-drive-and-refresh-pc) question. I've already done this solution (rebuilding the bootloader) many times. Clean installation is the last solution, because it will require more time consuming.

My goal is restoring the windows installation to this custom image. What am I supposed to do?