# "Drive where Windows is installed is locked" and no USB devices are working

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, drivers, windows-10

Problems:

1. No USB device works (including mice/keyboards)
2. Tried doing a Reset with the repair disk but I cannot ("Drive where Windows is installed is locked")
3. Can't boot into safe mode as for whatever reason, there just is no option to in this boot repair environment.
4. No other options in the boot repair environment work.
5. I can't unlock the drive by doing a clean shut down because #1
6. Teamviewer was working for a little while but won't anymore even after rebooting

At a complete loss. I've run `chkdsk /r`, `sfc /scannow` and numerous other commands in the repair cmd prompt with no success.

Last thing I did was attempt to clean the GPU driver by doing a complete uninstall of AMD software/drivers via Catalyst. I then used DDU to clean things further (this is what I suspect to be the larger problem creator). It's right when I clicked yes to a "go into safe mode to remove drivers" prompt that the USB's went dead.

If I could somehow force unlock the installation as seen by the repair disk, I'm fine doing a Reset. I've booted into Ubuntu Live and used ntfsfix & ntfs-3g tools to clean the hibernation/read-only stuff but it still is locked somehow (I can mount in Linux rw).

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/642276/how-to-unlock-a-hard-drive-and-refresh-pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was load my physical disk up in a virtual machine from a live Ubuntu CD to be able to get the Reset going.